Multiple comparison tests when removing the intercept?
I have a set of 13 different dependent variables, all tested against 9 independent variables. Here's a simplified example of the tests I'm running using R syntax:
first_dep ~ first_indep-1
first_dep ~ second_indep-1
first_dep ~ third_indep-1
...
thirteenth_dep ~ first_indep-1

I have a total of 117 tests. The -1 here represents removing the intercept, so that rather than testing each category within a variable against each other, it tests each category against 0.
Because I'm interested in testing each category against 0, do I still need to correct for multiple comparisons? I ran some code using a Holm correction, which tests all pairwise comparisons, but since I'm not interested in comparing groups, I don't think its needed.
